# How to execute insert or update database table in jpa hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, save

My problem is that I'm creating a job with spring boot that brings data from SAP BUSINESS ONE and stores it into sqlserver database, the problem is that my program is working the first time but when I re-execute it it doesn't work which sounds logical to me because I'm working with jpa save() method, the method saveOrUpdate method isn't working ( it says that it is undefined ) and I'm stuck! anyone help?

I expect the method to keep bringing data from SAP, if data already exists in my database then update, else then insert

Answer (score 0):

Save() method should be fine if you are using spring JPA.

Please share any snippets for understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah cause i used it for another project nd its working just fine ! i dont know wht's going wrong here !

```js
sql dao : 

@Repository
@Qualifier("ClientRepository")
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<ma.net.munisys.entities.sql.Client, String> {


 
 @Query(value="select code, name from MRH_VGR.dbo.customer",nativeQuery = true)
 public List<ma.net.munisys.entities.sql.Client> findClientSql();
 
 
}


sap dao : 



@Repository
@Qualifier("ClientRepository2")
public interface ClientRepository2 extends JpaRepository<Client, String> {

 @Query(value="select T.\"CardCode\" as code,T.\"CardName\" as name from \"DB_MUNISYS\".\"OCRD\" T where T.\"CardCode\" LIKE 'C%'",nativeQuery = true)
 public List<Client> findclientSap();
 
 
}
```

```css
entity : 

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;



@Entity
@Table(name="customer")
public class Client implements Serializable {
 
 @Id 
 private String code;
 private String name;
 private boolean disabled;
 

 
 

 public boolean isDisabled() {
  return disabled;
 }


 public void setDisabled(boolean disabled) {
  this.disabled = disabled;
 }


 public Client() {
  super();
 }

 public String getCode() {
  return code;
 }


 public void setCode(String code) {
  this.code = code;
 }


 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }


 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 



 @Override
 public String toString() {
  return "Client SQL [codeClient=" + code + ", client=" + name + "]";
 }
 
 @Override
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {

  
  Client client = (Client) obj;
  Boolean same = false;
  
  if (obj != null && obj instanceof Client)
        {
   if(client.getCode().equals(this.getName())) {
    same = true;
   }
        }
  
  return same;
 }





 
 
 
 
 

}
```

```html
code :

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

import ma.net.munisys.business.sql.ProjetBusiness;
import ma.net.munisys.business.sql.ProjetBusinessImpl;
import ma.net.munisys.entities.sql.Client;
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MunisysJobApplication {

    
  
  
  

  public  static List<ma.net.munisys.entities.sql.Client> clientSapToSql(List<ma.net.munisys.entities.sap.Client> clientsSap){
   
   List<ma.net.munisys.entities.sql.Client> clientSapToSql = new ArrayList<>();
   for(ma.net.munisys.entities.sap.Client client : clientsSap) {
    ma.net.munisys.entities.sql.Client clientSql = new ma.net.munisys.entities.sql.Client();
    if(client != null) {
    clientSql.setName(client.getName());
    clientSql.setCode(client.getCode());
    clientSapToSql.add(clientSql);
    }
   }
   return clientSapToSql;
   
   
  }
  
  
  
  
 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MunisysJobApplication.class, args);
  
  
  ProjetBusiness projetBusinessMysql = ctx.getBean(ProjetBusinessImpl.class);
  ma.net.munisys.business.sap.ProjetBusiness projetBusinessMysql2 = ctx.getBean(ma.net.munisys.business.sap.ProjetBusinessImpl2.class);

  List<Client> clientSapToSql = clientSapToSql(projetBusinessMysql2.findClientSap());
  List<Client> clientSql = projetBusinessMysql.findClientSql();
  List<Client> clients = new ArrayList<>();
     
     for(Client clientsap : clientSapToSql) {
      if(!clientSql.contains(clientsap)) {
       clients.add(clientsap);
       System.out.println(clientsap.toString());
       projetBusinessMysql.saveClient(clientsap);
      }
     }
     
     
     System.out.println("Difference " + clients.size());


 }
}
```